# In which instances do classrooms change floors in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

Recently, I came across J.K. Rowling saying this . . .

> "As obsessive fans will tell you, I do slip up! Several classrooms move floors mysteriously between books and these are the least serious continuity errors!"
> [Biggest Plot Holes in "Harry Potter"](https://www.businessinsider.com/harry-potter-plot-holes-2015-10#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CAs%20obsessive%20fans%20will%20tell,the%20direction%20of%20my%20mistakes.%22)

I don't ever recall the classrooms changing floors (of course, I may not be reading well).  So basically, my question is - in which instances do classrooms change floors/places in Harry Potter?

Comment: Year to year one could imagine classrooms changing places. Not that the school seemed to do many remodels.

Comment: @JonCuster Either JK Rowling's mistake, or magic. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find 'classrooms' changing floors but many rooms as a whole have changed floors in Harry Potter due to JK Rowling's mistake

**BOOKS**

First instance -

> At Nearly Headless Nick's Deathday party, Hermione says that Myrtle haunts the bathroom on the first floor. However, she should say on the second floor. Just before they find the writing on the wall, it says "Harry hurtled around the whole of the second floor" and when Hermione is talking to Myrtle, she says "because a cat was attacked just outside your front door on Halloween." Her bathroom is on the second floor, not on the first.

Second instance -

> In CoS, on page 119 of the American version, it states, "...Harry was dragging his feet along the SECOND floor corridor to Lockhart's office. He gritted his teeth and knocked." However, on page 141, after Mrs. Norris is found petrified on the second floor, Lockhart urges Professor Dumbledore to use his office to examine her, saying that it is just upstairs. That would mean that his office is on the THIRD floor, not the second.

**Movies**

Third instance  -

> In Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, the entrance to the Headmaster's Office is stated to be on the second floor. However, in Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, the entrance is on the seventh floor. This is easily explained, however, by Hogwarts' magically ever-changing floorplan.

[Source](https://www.indiaforums.com/forum/topic/24580)

Answer (score 3):

Although not strictly speaking a classroom, the Headmaster's Office is stated in the 4th book to be on the second floor, but in the 6th book it's described as being on the seventh floor. ([source](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Headmaster%27s_office#Behind_the_scenes))

Comment: You could improve this answer by editing it to include any relevant quotes from the wiki page you linked to. If you could include direct quotes from the source material, that'd be even better.